# Tracking error Mage_Freight_Helper_Data on Editing permission roles

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, helper, permissions

The magento is giving this error when i access index.php/admin/permissions_role/editrole/rid/1/:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mage_Freight_Helper_Data' not found in ../app/Mage.php:547 Stack trace: #0 ../app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Roles.php(160): Mage::helper('freight') #1 ..app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Roles.php(175): Mage_Admin_Model_Roles->_buildResourcesArray(Object(Varien_Simplexml_Element), 'admin/system/co...', 6, NULL, false, 'freight') #2 app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Roles.php(175): Mage_Admin_Model_Roles->_buildResourcesArray(Object(Varien_Simplexml_Element), 'admin/system/co...', 5, NULL, false, 'adminhtml') #3 /usr/share/nginx/sites/brascool/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Roles.php(175): Mage_Admin_Model_Roles->_buildResourcesArray(Object(Varien_Simplexml_Element), 'admin/system', 4, NULL, false, 'adminhtml') #4 /usr/share/nginx/sites/brascool/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Roles.php(175): Mage_Admin_Model_Roles->_buildResourcesArray(Object(Varien_Simplexml_Element), 'admi in app/Mage.php on line 547
```

I dont remember change anything recently.

How can i track where this Class Mage_Freight_Helper_Data is called to remove?
I tried check in database some rewrite but i cannot found anything.

```
Configuração errada de tabulação.

#0 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Editroles.php(42): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->addTab('account', false)
#1 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_Editroles->_prepareLayout()
#2 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#3 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/permi...', 'adminhtml.permi...')
#4 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/permi...', 'adminhtml.permi...')
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#8 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(285): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/RoleController.php(44): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#11 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/RoleController.php(105): Mage_Adminhtml_Permissions_RoleController->_initAction()
#12 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Permissions_RoleController->editRoleAction()
#13 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('editrole')
#14 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
```

PS: I tried clear cache and reindex, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed recently some extension something like `Freight` Module, or you have created a module and you call or declared not well you helper. You helper should looks like this:

**app/code/local/Package/Module/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php
class Package_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

in **Xml** part:

```
...
<global>
    <helpers>
        <module>
            <class>Package_Module_Helper</class>
        </module>
    </helpers>
</global>
...
```

Then you call your helper like this:

```
Mage::helper('module')
```

Exemple:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('module')->__('Hi helper')?>
```

Comment: No, I have not installed any recent modules. Is it possible to identify where the magento is searching for this extension / where it is being called?

Comment: check in app/code/local, or app/code/community or in SSH `grep -rni "Mage::helper('freight')"`